# posting a form but without posting the viewstate

Tags: c#, asp.net, forms, get

I have a web form and want to 'get' it to another page..
is there anyway to submit it without posting the `ViewState` and other bits I don't want?

Or should I be catching the submit button click and redirecting with a querystring I build myself.

Comment: Sorry the question is not clear to me. Do you want to navigate to a different ASPX file or do you want the values of your web form to be processed by a different ASPX file?

Comment: i have a page that has a number of search options on it, this will load the search in a new page - as the search results page is different to the search page.
i want to post using get so that the 'searches' can be bookmarked.. 
but if i set the form to get, then the viewstate is also posted- as are all fields regardless of whether they have been selected/data added
i really only want to post (get) fields that are selected/have data in them to the search results page..
wondered if there is a way that this can be done semi automatically.

Comment: Not quite sure *why* you don't want to post the ViewState as it will be storing the data from your form. If there is an issue with your post and you go back to your form it means all your data will be lost

Comment: cont. or i should add an event to the search button, and get the data from the form myself then redirect to the results page building the QS myself

Comment: Do you have any other features on the main page that requires the use of the ViewState (controls with postback, etc)?

Comment: nope, just want the options picked to stick their values in the qs for the results page.. this will most likely open in a new window anyway, so not at all worried about the search page at all really..

Comment: Ok, I posted a suggestion based on your inputs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a couple of options here:

- [Disable ViewState](https://web.archive.org/web/20150103022221/http://www.ironspeed.com/articles/Disable%20View%20State%20for%20a%20Page/Article.aspx)
- [Use jQuery to remove the fields you don't want to post before the are sent to the server](http://api.jquery.com/remove/)

You don't have to disable ViewState on all pages, just the pages that you do not care for the state to be saved.

But there is also the option to disable the ViewState completely if you never want to use it.

If you just want to compose a GET by yourself, you can use jQuery for that aswell so you only pass the parameters you really want which will give you 100% control of what is posted /getted.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not using the `viewstate`, why have you kept it enabled? Just disable it. For every server control, set the `EnableViewState = False` and you are free from it. If you need the `viewstate`, it will be part of the post all the time.

Comment: Why not disable the ViewState at the Page level so? You can do it on Page directive or on the PageInit event.

Comment: Yes, that will be a better approach. Thanks @carlos.

Answer (score -1):

You could add an event handler to your search button and do something similar to this

```
private void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    String query = queryTextBox.Text;
    Response.Redirect("SearchResults.aspx?query=" + query);
}
```

Using JavaScript

```
function doSearch()
{
    // Assuming you are not using jQuery, 
    // using jQuery it would be $('#queryTextBox').value instead
    var queryString = document.getElementById('queryTextBox').value;

    window.open("SearchResults.aspx?query=" + queryString);
    return false;
}
```

Html

```
<input type="text" id="queryTextBox" />
<input type="button" onclick="return doSearch()" value="Go" />
```

Comment: hi
thanks yes this was my initial thought.. just felt a bit like there may be a way to deal with this automatically.. 
as mentioned in another answer maybe jquery get would be a nice option as it would avoid a trip to the server

Comment: @Carlos, that would require 2 transfers / calls to the server which causes overhead.

Comment: dont care if it uses the viewstate or not really, just dont want it in the QS, or the eventvalidation and other associated cr*p just the fields that have been selected in some way..

Comment: @Filip I know that. The question didn't mentioned any concern about doing more than one round trip to the server.

Comment: @Carlos, why would you ever want to do that? It's bad design.

Comment: @Filip Please show me an example of a good design, so I can learn how it looks like.

Answer (score -1):

There are different ways to persist viewstate.

I have had in the past, had to persist viewstate on the server (using ApplicationState/Session, cant remember) for a heavy AJAX page to support faster updates. Works well.

See `Page.LoadPageStateFromPersistenceMedium` and `Page.SavePageStateToPersistenceMedium`.

Sorry, no links from Reflector available.